# How to convert greyscale to alpha in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color

I have a scanned image I converted to outlines in Illustrator.
To do that, I have used the greyscale option, which gave me a decent result.

What I need to do now is to convert the greyscale values to transparent blacks. For example:

```
HSL: 0/0/0   to HSLA: 0/0/0/0   (black to solid black)
HSL: 0/0/50  to HSLA: 0/0/0/0.5 (50% grey to half transparent black)
HSL: 0/0/100 to HSLA: 0/0/0/1   (white to full transparent black)
```

Since I need to do that with a lot of images with a lot of different greyscale swatches I would be glad to know a way to automate it rather than doing it by hand.
Is there any way to do this easily?

Comment: the final output would be vector?

Comment: @Yorik yes, I want to export it as an svg for web usage.

Comment: I don't know of any method within Illustrator to do this. It *may* be possible via scripting though - something to read the value of k and set transparency to that value, then set k to 100%.